# I'm having trouble loggin in using puppeteer . Also can't find the selector for sign in button in the site provided bellow

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Bellow is the code i'm trying, please help!**
i'm facing two problems, 
1. the browser is opening at http://164.52.197.129/signin but after a certain time it goes back to http://164.52.197.129
2. I can't locate the sign in button selector. the selector i'm choosing is not working , maybe because it's nested .

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
// const URL = 'http://164.52.197.129/signin';
const chromeOptions = {
  headless:false,
  defaultViewport: null};
(async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  //await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
console.log("Opening page");
  await page.goto(('http://164.52.197.129/signin'), { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' , timeout: 60000 });
console.log("Page opened");
await page.waitForSelector('#email', {timeout: 60000});
console.log("Inputting username");
await page.type('#email', 'guest@gmail.com');
console.log("Username input completed");
await page.waitForSelector('#password', {timeout: 60000});
console.log("Inputting password");
await page.type('#password', 'sdah1234');
console.log("Password input completed");
await page.click('#app > div > main > div > div > div > form > div > div.v-card__text > div > div.text-xs-center.col > button');
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest such algorithm:

1. Open the page.
2. Wait for the redirection (carousel appears).
3. Require signing form again (clicking on the link by `page.click()` does not work, so we are using `page.evaluate()`).
4. Wait for the form.
5. As the form is autocompleted before `page.type()` and the input is doubled, we are using `page.evaluate()` again.
6. Click and wait for navigation in `Promise.all()` to avoid a race condition.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const chromeOptions = {
  headless:false,
  defaultViewport: null};

(async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(('http://164.52.197.129/signin'), { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' , timeout: 60000 });

  await page.waitForSelector('.carousel-3d-container');
  await page.waitForSelector('a[href="/signin"]');
  await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('a[href="/signin"]').click(); });

  await page.waitForSelector('#email', {timeout: 60000});
  await page.waitForSelector('#password', {timeout: 60000});

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#email').value = 'guest@gmail.com';
    document.querySelector('#password').value = 'sdah1234';
  });

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('#app form button'),
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}),
  ]);

  console.log("Done");
})();
```